# delphi : Connect to yahoo web messenger with idhttp

Tags: delphi, yahoo, idhttp

i use delphi xe2 and write a simple code to connect to yahoo web messenger
but i get this message

> If you are seeing this page, your browser settings prevent you from
>   automatically redirecting to a new UR

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
idVar:TStringList;
Cookies:string;
begin
 idVar:=TStringList.Create; idVar.Clear;
 idVar.Add('.tries=1');
 idVar.Add('.src=vsu');
 idVar.Add('.md5=');
 idVar.Add('.hash=');
 idVar.Add('.js=');
 idVar.Add('.last=');
 idVar.Add('promo=');
 idVar.Add('.intl=us');
 idVar.Add('.bypass=');
 idVar.Add('.partner=');
 idVar.Add('.u=3p9b5hh7aiqbl');
 idVar.Add('.v=0');
 idVar.Add('.challenge=J5TQOMzQ9Sr5hwnIHYMiVyI2i1_M');
 idVar.Add('.yplus=');
 idVar.Add('.emailCode=');
 idVar.Add('pkg=');
 idVar.Add('stepid=');
 idVar.Add('.ev=');
 idVar.Add('hasMsgr=0');
 idVar.Add('.chkP=Y');
 idVar.Add('.done=http://webmessenger.yahoo.com/');
 idVar.Add('.pd=wmsgr_ver=0&c=B_VH9oa42e68KuzJEhSlKbE-&ivt=&sg=');
 idVar.Add('login='+edt1.Text);
 idVar.Add('passwd='+edt2.Text);
 idVar.Add('.persistent=y');
  Memo1.Text:=idhtp1.Post('https://login.yahoo.com/config/login?',idVar);
end;

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
idhtp1.CookieManager:=idckmngr1;
idhtp1.IOHandler:=idslhndlrscktpnsl1;
idhtp1.RedirectMaximum:=5000;
idhtp1.Request.BasicAuthentication:=False;
idhtp1.HandleRedirects := True;

idslhndlrscktpnsl1.SSLOptions.Method:=sslvSSLv23;
idhtp1.Request.UserAgent:='Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)';
end;

procedure TForm2.idhtp1Redirect(Sender: TObject; var dest: string;
  var NumRedirect: Integer; var Handled: Boolean; var VMethod: string);
begin
Handled:=True;
end;
```

Comment: You don't have to call `Clear` on a newly created string list. They already start out that way.

Comment: Does the code ever reach the line `Handled := True`?

Comment: @lord_viper: this is difficult to diagnose without seeing the complete HTTP traffic back and forth.  Please show that. All you have shown is a text message, which is not enough info.  Chances are, the server is NOT sending a redirection reply when that text message appears, and there are several factors that could contribute to that happening.  My guess is either the initial request is invalid/malformed to begin with, or the server did issue a redirect that TIdHTTP followed but the followup request was invalid/malformed in some way, or maybe a required cookie was not carried over, etc.

Answer (score 1):

> If you are seeing this page, your browser settings prevent you from
>   automatically redirecting to a new URL.

This came to Fiddler as `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` so problem is not with redirect.

What worked for me was simply repeating whole `Button1Click` after this message came and I logged in correctly. The cookies that were collected in meantime was the key so you could try send only one request but with cookies pre-setted. Or if it not helps, just repeat request with collected cookies. TIdCookieManager to rescue!